# HTTP protocol violation on web application start up

Tags: web-services, jsp, http, tomcat, fiddler

I’m checking on [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) what's coming in and going out though the Tomcat port while I’m running my Web application. I keep seeing the following error on the very first call:

```
X-HTTPPROTOCOL-VIOLATION: [ProtocolViolation] Incorrectly formed Request-Line. abs_path was empty (e.g. missing /). RFC2616 Section 5.1.2.
```

The file being loaded is `index.jsp`, a plain jsp file configured as a `welcome-file` in `web.xml`.

Everything else in this JSP page and elsewhere in the application are running fine. I haven’t seen this error on any other calls either.

Why is this protocol violation error occurring? How crucial is it? How do I fix it?

I’m using Tomcat 8. I’m starting the project from within Eclipse, just by running the web application on this `index.jsp`, passing any protocol settings. Is this causing the problem?

Comment: Please do not delete this question. Stack Overflow should be a repository of programming knowledge.

Comment: @TRiG ok i guess. would remind me stuff as well when i look up long after.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message specifies the problem precisely. The request being sent to Tomcat is not following the requirements on absolute path set in RFC2616. The chances are Eclipse doesn't abide by RFC2616.

Most probably the request is violating this - "Note that the absolute path cannot be empty; if none is present in the original URI, it MUST be given as "/" (the server root)."  If you post the HTTP request as you see it in Fiddler we'll know for sure.

Fiddler is designed to abide by the HTTP specs completely and that's why it issues this warning.